# Horizontal scroll from right to left

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

[JSFiddle for horizontal slide of divs](http://jsfiddle.net/sg3s/rs2QK/)

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $('a.panel').click(function() {
    var $target = $($(this).attr('href')),
        $other = $target.siblings('.active');

    if (!$target.hasClass('active')) {
        $other.each(function(index, self) {
            var $this = $(this);
            $this.removeClass('active').animate({
                left: $this.width()
            }, 500);
        });

        $target.addClass('active').show().css({
            left: -($target.width())
        }).animate({
            left: 0
        }, 500);
    }
  });
});
```

I this fiddle divs are sliding from left to right.What i need is reverse.Slide from right to left.

Comment: Did you try marginLeft wiht marginRight ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to reverse the function providing the animation. Instead of

```
left: -($target.width())
```

I put the following

```
left: -($(this).width() - ($target.width()))
```

Here is my runnable solution:

```js
jQuery(function($) {

    $('a.panel').click(function() {
        var $target = $($(this).attr('href')),
            $other = $target.siblings('.active');
        
        if (!$target.hasClass('active')) {
            $other.each(function(index, self) {
                var $this = $(this);
                $this.removeClass('active').animate({
                    left: 0
                }, 500);
            });

            $target.addClass('active').show().css({
                left: -($(this).width() - ($target.width()))
            }).animate({
                left: 0
            }, 500);
        }
    });

});
```

```css
#left, #right {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 5px 0 0;
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

div.panel {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="left">
    <a href="#target1" class="panel">Target 1</a><br/>
    <a href="#target2" class="panel">Target 2</a><br/>
    <a href="#target3" class="panel">Target 3</a><br/>
</div>

<div id="right">
    <div class="panel" id="target1" style="background:green">Target 1</div>
    <div class="panel" id="target2" style="background:red">Target 2</div>
    <div class="panel" id="target3" style="background:yellow">Target 3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it will do the work if I understood what you want:

Here is the jsfiddle updated: http://jsfiddle.net/rs2QK/3891/

And the javascript updated:
jQuery(function($) {

```
$('a.panel').click(function() {
    var $target = $($(this).attr('href')),
        $other = $target.siblings('.active');

    if (!$target.hasClass('active')) {
        $other.each(function(index, self) {
            var $this = $(this);
            $this.removeClass('active').animate({
                left: -($target.width())
            }, 500);
        });
    }
  $target.addClass('active')
  .css({
    left: -($target.width())})
  .show()
  .animate({
    left: 0}, 500);
  });
});
```

```js
jQuery(function($) {

    $('a.panel').click(function() {
        var $target = $($(this).attr('href')),
            $other = $target.siblings('.active');
        
        if (!$target.hasClass('active')) {
            $other.each(function(index, self) {
                var $this = $(this);
                $this.removeClass('active').animate({
                    left: -($target.width())
                }, 500);
            });
        }
      $target.addClass('active')
      .css({
       left: -($target.width())})
      .show()
      .animate({
       left: 0}, 500);
    });

});
```

```css
#left, #right {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 5px 0 0;
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

div.panel {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="left">
    <a href="#target1" class="panel">Target 1</a><br/>
    <a href="#target2" class="panel">Target 2</a><br/>
    <a href="#target3" class="panel">Target 3</a><br/>
</div>

<div id="right">
    <div class="panel" id="target1" style="background:green">Target 1</div>
    <div class="panel" id="target2" style="background:red">Target 2</div>
    <div class="panel" id="target3" style="background:yellow">Target 3</div>
</div>
```